# Is there any start and end for order property in flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to know that is there any begin or end number for arranging elements in a flex container ?
For example :

```
.firstOrder {
    order: <First-Item>
}
```

Why ? Because I want to create a CSS framework, So I want to know can I add 2 classes to order First item and Last item.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there are not any specific start or end number.

Any number is usable, both positive and negative, and the one's with lower comes first, and a flex item's default is `0`.

If two, or more, items have the same value, it is their order in the markup that decides.

---

In your case, having a first and last, and based on the default of `0`, giving one item `-1` and another `1`, will make the item with `-1` first and the item with `1` last.

---

Based on a comment by [Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690759/is-there-any-start-and-end-for-order-property-in-flex/47690808#comment82340833_47690808), it should be noted that older Flexbox versions might have a different default value, e.g. it appears for `-webkit-box-ordinal-group` to be `1`.

Comment: Exactly, order can have any integer value (including negative).

Comment: Thanks, You know in http://flexboxgrid.com/, It has added 2 classes that one of them has -1 value and second one has +1 for first and last item.

Comment: Please mention in your post that -(webkit, moz)-box-ordinal-group has 1 for default value, So for first item It needs 0 and for last item it needs 2.

Comment: @LGSon ;) Thank you.

Comment: @AliBahaari If to make your own first/last class, I would consider to use a higher value, e.g. -50/50, so also items between first and last could be re-ordered, as with -1/1 it will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such specific option like pseudo in CSS. How some tricky way is

order first `order: -9999;`

order last `order: 9999;`

order none `order: 0;`